# :last isn't working

Tags: jquery

`jQuery(".xg_module_body .postbody a:last").addClass("continue");`

Is there something wrong w/ that code? The class doesn't get added for some reason.

I'm trying to add a link to just the last `a` in `.postbody`. I've tried `:last-child` and it adds a class to both `a` tags. So why wouldn't `:last` work?

```
<div class="xg_module_body">
    <h3>
        <span>
            <a href="link">
                <img src="image url">
            </a>
        </span>
        <a href="link">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="postbody">
        <p>
            <a href="link"><img src="image url"></a>
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <a href="link">Continue</a>
    </div>
    <p class="small">
        <a href="link">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="link">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen here, it does work : http://jsfiddle.net/B9CwH/

I'm betting your selector is wrong. The snippet you pasted doesn't have a `.xg_module_body`

```
<div class="postbody">
     <p>
          <a href="link"><img src="image"></a>
     </p>
     <p>title</p>
     <a href="link">Continue</a>
</div>

$(".postbody a:last").addClass("continue");
```

Comment: I actually omitted that part from the html but it is there. Also, I just tried what you suggested but it didn't work. Both `a` and `a:last-child` works. Only `a:last` doesn't work. Strange...

Comment: Why not post the whole HTML here?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my original post to include the full html.

Comment: I noticed it does actually work if I put it in jFiddle. So maybe there is something else that is wrong. Is there an alternate solution that you know of by any chance?

Comment: @harry hard to say without looking at the page. It could be that your HTML is malformed so that the selector is misfiring. Have you tried inspecting it with firebug to make sure the path is correct?

Comment: The thing that's throwing me off is the fact that `.xg_module_body .postbody a` and `.xg_module_body .postbody a:last-child` works fine. It adds the class to both `a` tags (as it should).

Comment: @harry, according to your structure that's wrong. `postbody` is wrapped around only `continue` link. It should only apply to 1 link. If it's applying to two links, then you probably have an unclosed tag.

Comment: I checked the html and validated it and nothing came up about an unclosed tag. Is there a way to choose the last element of `postbody` so I can see what it selects?

Comment: @harry, yeah you can do `.postbody *:last`. That will select the last child.

Comment: I tried `jQuery(".postbody *:last").addClass("continue");` and nothing within div.postbody got an added class of 'continue'. Strange. If you have any other ideas, I'm open to it. If not, thanks so much for helping me.

Comment: @harry no problem, I'm pretty sure your HTML is at fault here. Not much I can do about a solution unless you have a page available online.

Answer (score 1):

working perfect:

see here :

### http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/q5jK2/

**other way :** try with **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**:

```
$('.postbody').filter(':last').addClass("continue");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/q5jK2/3/)**

Comment: I see that it's working. Why wouldn't it work on mine? Is there an alternate solution?

Comment: also working with your updated HTML see here : http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/q5jK2/2/  . In which browser your are facing the problem??

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too and it does work. Do you know of another way to select the last `a` tag by any chance?